# Hit count for sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to know how many times a list/library/page is accessed like a hit count on 2013 sites. Can you tell me where can I get that information? The web analytics is not available in 2013 so I guess Search is used to get the info. Is it true? If so how to get the info

Answer (score 4):

You can access some analytics from your site settings page in the section Site Collection Administration called Popularity and Search reports.

[image]

On that page you have a few options, where one is page (item) views

[image]

If that's not enough you need to use a 3rd party tool.

Reference: [SharePoint 2013 Web Analytics Report - Where is it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2013/08/31/sharepoint-2013-web-analytics-report-where-is-it.aspx)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I have already looked into it and the problem is I'm not getting the URL vs count information

Comment: @ChandraShekhar In the comment section of the reference link above, there are a few suggestions of tools to try. I haven't tried any of them (yet) but from the comments it looks that IT Pros are satisfied with them